# How to print a timestamp with the docker stats

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-18.04

I am checking for the CPU spike in docker containers? I need the timestamp where the CPU spike generates so that I can check the logs for the container for that timestamp.

I am running the `docker stats --no-stream` command to Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics and got the below output

[image]

now I want to see the timestamp also, is there a way to achieve this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a shell script to print a timestamp before printing the metrics from `docker stats` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
now=$(date +'%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M')

while true; do printf "\n$(date +'%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M_%S'):\n" | tee --append stats_$now.txt;  docker stats --no-stream | tee --append stats_$now.txt; sleep 1; done
```

Sample output below:

[image]